# Tough Javascript Question : Read DropDown Values and Show it as clickable links in Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]
My Drop down HTML code looks like below,

```
<select onchange="if (this.value != '') {Add_Search_Param('f-' + this.value.split('|')[1], this.value.split('|')[0]); Refine();}"><option value="">Find by Model Number</option><option value="45|V709">V709 (6)</option><option value="52|V714">V714 (4)</option></select>
```

Currently the above HTML code displays a drop down which shows the following

Find by Model Number, V709 (6), V714 (4).

What i need done is read the Drop Down, display in the same page but instead of drop down make it clickable links, something like below.

```
<a href="V709 (6).htm">V709 (6)</a>
```

So is this possible ?

Comment: You need to go and accept some answers to your questions, otherwise people will stop answering them

Comment: Hmm only 55% of my questions are answered and i have Accepted that

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div id="links"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('option').each(function(){
    $('#links')
    .append(
        $('<a />')
        .attr({ href:$(this).text()+'.htm' })
        .html( $(this).text()+'<br>' )
    )
})
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TJV4K/

Notes:
This requires jQuery javascript library, but any other decent library can be used in a very similar way.

You need to give an id to the select you are targeting and modify the selector in the javascript code so it picks the right option tags - as it stands, it will pick all option tags on the page.

Comment: Great thanks for the solution that works, but one issues and its my fault not yours actually that page has 3 more Drop downs 
Find by Width
Find by Color
Find by Offset

 how to read those as well ?

Comment: Ok i checked it and thanks for the answer few more questions :

Here is my url where i have integrated the code http://tinyurl.com/3tev5fd ( check left navigation )

Your code is Displaying all the Drop Downs as links i want to only display values of following as links

Find by Model Number
Find by Diameter
Find by Width
Find by Color
Find by Offset
and remove all others
Is this possible ?

Comment: You should give an `id` to each `select` tag like this `<select id="myModelNumber">...</select>` and then identify in jQuery like this `$("#myModelNumber option, #myDiameter option, etc...").each( etc...`

Comment: Unfortunately giving id is not possible since the code is coming from different website. 

Can we have something like if   $('option')=="Price: Low to High"

STOP displaying the links ? 

Is this possible how to change the above code ?

Comment: Not as reliable a solution, but you could do something like: `$('#content_area option:lt(4)').each( etc...` which just means within the element with id `content_area`, select all `option` tags less than `4`, so `0,1,2,3`. But this only works whilst their format remains identical.

Comment: Yes that will work because the drop downs wont changes, so how do i modify the following code ?

$('option').each(function(){
    $('#links')
    .append(
        $('<a />')
        .attr({ href:$(this).text()+'.htm' })
        .html( $(this).text()+'<br>' )
    )
})

Comment: come on, you got to do some of it yourself, do you want me to code it for you and collect your salary for you too? I have already given you the answer, just put it together. If you want to learn more, read up about jQuery selectors.